# Using flyway - How can memory optimized tables be deployed

Tags: sql-server, deployment, flyway

I am using Flyway Community Edition 6.3.2 by Redgate and attempting to deploy a memory optimized table.

The content of my versioned script is...

```
CREATE TABLE temp_memory_optimized.test 
( 
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY); 
GO
```

On deploy time I am seeing this error...

```
ERROR: Migration of schema [dbo] to version 1.0.2 - add memory optimized objects failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
ERROR:
Migration v1.0.2__add_memory_optimized_objects.sql failed
---------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : S000109
Error Code : 12331
Message    : DDL statements ALTER, DROP and CREATE inside user transactions are not supported with memory optimized tables.
Location   : C:\...\v1.0.2__add_memory_optimized_objects.sql (C:\...\v1.0.2__add_memory_optimized_objects.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE TABLE temp_memory_optimized.test
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY);
```

MO filegroup is configured correctly and I can successfully manually deploy onto my test box.

I have set `-mixed=true` on the migrate command.

I know I cannot be the first person to hit this problem however internet searches are proving fruitless in trying to track down a solution.

Comment: The workaround in [issue 2062](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2062) seems relevant, given the lack of Flyway 6.x documentation concerning this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [issue 2062](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2062) Flyway is not detecting that
`CREATE TABLE WITH MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON` is not valid in a transaction automatically. You will need to override this behaviour on a per-script basis as detailed here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/scriptconfigfiles and will need to do so for each CREATE/ALTER/DELETE on in-memory objects.

Comment: Thanks @Julia Hayward and AlwaysLearning for the replies. Yes, when I added the script specific config file with the correct options it is now deploying successfully.